# scrapy get start_urls from database

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a question want to ask
If I sant to select the link from database and let it be the `start_urls`
What can I do ??

assum  my database save these link and title

```
1: link : 'http://test.com/id=1'  ,  title : 'math'   
2: link : 'http://test.com/id=2'  ,  title : 'english'       
3: link : 'http://test.com/id=30' ,  title : 'sports'
```

and if I can get the title as a parameter in my spider would be better.

Here is my thought:

```
class MySpider(Spider):  
    name = "linktest"
    for obj in Learning.objects.all():
        print obj.link
        #result: http://test.com/id=1
                 http://test.com/id=2
                 http://test.com/id=30
    start_urls =[ 'http://test.com/id=1',  #how to do this?
                  'http://test.com/id=2',
                  'http://test.com/id=30' ]

    def parse(self, response):
        #item['title']=math     #when response.url ==  http://test.com/id=1,
        #item['title']=english  #when response.url ==  http://test.com/id=2,...
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to override [`start_requests()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests) method and `yield`/`return` [`Request`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) instances from it:

> This method must return an iterable with the first Requests to crawl
>   for this spider.
>
> This is the method called by Scrapy when the spider is opened for
>   scraping when no particular URLs are specified.

```
class MySpider(Spider):  
    name = "linktest"

    def start_requests(self):
        for obj in Learning.objects.all():
            yield Request(obj.link)
```

---

In order to pass an `obj.title` to the callback, use [`meta`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) attribute:

```
class MySpider(Spider):  
    name = "linktest"

    def start_requests(self):
        for obj in Learning.objects.all():
            yield Request(obj.link, meta={'title': obj.title})

    def parse(self, response):
        print response.url, response.meta['title']
```